# property of $A\rightarrow C$ tautology with mutual atomic proposition.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

given $A\rightarrow C$ is a tautology in proposition calculus, and there is at least one mutual atomic proposition which appears in $A$ and $C$. Prove that, there is a proposition B which is formed only by proposition which are mutual for A and C such that $A\rightarrow B$ and $B\rightarrow C$ and tautologies.

I have figure it out that in case that A is a contradiction, $p\vee\neg p$ when p is a mutual proposition, will stand for B. Yet this doesn't hold in general.
I am trying to target the fact that any true/false assignment to the matual proposition doesn't change $A\rightarrow C$ proposition what means there is no difference if mutual proposition $p$ appears as $\neg p $ or $p$.

Comment: Please, what does it mean "mutual" in this context ?

Comment: Maybe useful [Craig interpolation lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig_interpolation).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA mutual means the proposition p appears in both A and C for example $A:= p$ and $C:= (q \rightarrow p)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA can you please explain what is the meaning of replacing P with T and "twisted T" as demonstrated in the proof of Craig lemma?

Comment: $\top$ is the *propositional constant* that is always TRUE while $\bot$ is FALSE.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA it says (in the wiki link) that Craig lemma is valid also in first order logic. Does the respective lemma is for $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ which share free-variables' and $\alpha \rightarrow \gamma$ is a logical truth?